# require('fs') to read/write with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, txt

i want to read/write text local file
I'm using fs like this

```
import * as fs from "fs";
const result = fs.readFileSync("sCode.txt", { encoding: "utf-8" });
console.log(result);
```

but i got this console error `TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.readFileSync is not a function`

how can i use `fs` with vuejs or if there another way to `read/write` local file

Comment: fs is Node import, you can't run it in a browser. It would be inadmissible for a website to have access to local files from arbitrary path

Comment: how can I access the file just in code to read/write on it, not in the browser @EstusFlask

Comment: Where then? Vue app runs in a browser